# td .cssClass - is this a valid construct?

Tags: css, html-table

I got doubt on this fundamental css.

> "*tbody tr td .plusIcon*"  is not taken. Instead, "*.plusIcon*" is taken.

Please let me know how to override *.plusIcon* within *tbody tr td*?

```css
tbody tr td .plusIcon {
  color: red;
}
tbody tr td .minusIcon {
  color: brown;
}
.plusIcon {
  color: silver;
}
.minusIcon {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="plusIcon">Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No, this is not valid CSS. This is Sass / SCSS, via https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: The question in the title can be answered with "yes" though. It is valid, as is the output from the SCSS compiler. The question is, why do you think .plusicon would not work inside a table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a preprocessor like sass, you can nest selectors like that. Not with normal css though.

With normal css you would need to do

```css
tbody tr td .plusIcon {
  background: url(../img/left-arrow-blue.png) 15px 18px no-repeat;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-left: 42px;
}
tbody tr td  .minusIcon {              
  background: url(../img/down-arrow-blue.png) 15px 18px no-repeat;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-left: 42px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much _teevik_. also, i found **[less playground](http://fiddlesalad.com/less/)** useful place to test around.

Comment: @SanjaiPrabahar You have accepted this answer, but it doesn't address the latest version of your question. You might be better off asking a new question then, unless you figured out what the problem in the current snippet is, in which case you can post an answer of your own. Hint: it's a space too many.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work as it is not valid CSS-Syntax.

Valid CSS would look like this:

```
tbody tr td .plusIcon {
    background: url(../img/left-arrow-blue.png) 15px 18px no-repeat;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-left: 42px;
}

tbody tr td .minusIcon {
    background: url(../img/down-arrow-blue.png) 15px 18px no-repeat;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-left: 42px;
}
```

For best practices and fundamentels you should just use Google an search for this.

Comment: @op, you could also use less element nesting to accomplish the same thing. Makes your CSS easier to mantain

Comment: Sure would look in google. also, i found **[less playground](http://fiddlesalad.com/less/)** useful place to test around.